# Angular GET json array

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, get

i want to know how i can save the json array from my GET Request on a variable. I am working on a search service and can already search for user but also want to search for Moods (similar to Tweets).

This sends a GET request to the elastic db and requestes MoodTexts(Posts with Text and emoji). If i search for "green", my request finds 4 results in the database and my searchbar in the html shows 4 blank results, but i want to post the found text in those blank fields. Btw Mood is a class with the variable "text".

Component (i think here is the mistake):

```
mood: Mood[];

getMood() {
    const moodText = this.angForm2.value.searchText;
    console.log(this.angForm2.value, moodText);
    this.searchservice.getElasticPostsResult(moodText).subscribe((data2: any) => {
      this.mood = data2.hits.hits;
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="textSearch" *ngFor="let moodText of mood">
    <br><a id="a2">{{moodText?.text}}</a>
  </div>
```

Console/Request output:

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get? In the JSON output there is no text data ... Which data are you trying to access?

Comment: In the json is under f.e. hits.hits[0]._source is a variable "text" i want to output that on my searchbar results. The error i get is "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<div id="textSearch" *ngFor="let moodText of mood">
    <br><a id="a2">{{moodText['_source']?.text}}</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access mood you can use the below way.

```
<div id="textSearch" *ngFor="let moodText of mood">
    <br><a id="a2">{{moodText?._source.text}}</a>
  </div>
```

The text is coming inside the _source object.